# Unable to render my Images with Gatsby and Strapi, tried different queries as well

Tags: gatsby, strapi

im trying to render a single image using Gatsby and Strapi and I have not been able to do so,

Here is my current GraphiQL query, I have not been able to find a local option and when I utulize the childImageSharp I get no image either.

```
export const query = graphql`
  {
    allStrapiProject {
      nodes {
        description
        featured
        github
        id
        slug
        title
        url
        stack {
          id
          title
        }
        image {
          id
        }
      }
    }
  }
`
```

Here is my Gatsby Component

```
  description,
  title,
  github,
  stack,
  url,
  image,
  index,
  slug,
 }) => {
  return(
     <article className="project">
    <GatsbyImage 
      image={getImage(image)}
      className="project-img"
      alt={title}
     />
    <div className="project-info">
    <span className="project-number">0{index + 1}.</span>
    <Link to={`/rpojects/${slug}`} className="project-slug">
    <h3>{title}</h3>

    </Link>
   <p className="project-desc">{description}</p>
    <div className="project-stack">
      {stack.map(item => {
        return <span key={item.id}>{item.title}</span>
        
      })}
   </div>
    <div className="project-links">
      <a href={github}>
        <FaGithubSquare className="project-icon">
       </FaGithubSquare>
       </a>
      <a href={url}>
        <FaShareSquare className="project-icon">
       </FaShareSquare>
       </a>


    </div>



    </div> 
    </article>
  )
}

export default Project
```

Here is a screen shot of the actual project in development, everything else works perfectly fine.

Comment: Can you share your `gatsby-config.js` info?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You hit the nail with your issue: you need `childImageSharp` or `localFile` nodes (which hold your image data) to display the image.

You should look for something like:

```
{
  allStrapiProject {
    edges {
      node {
        id
        image {
          publicURL
        }
        multipleImages {
          localFile {
            publicURL
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Otherwise, your Strapi configuration should be wrong.

The implementation with `GatsbyImage` component looks good since fixed the node, your code should work alone.

If you can provide more details about your `gatsby-config.js` or a configuration of your `localhost:8000/___graphql` (where all the nodes are displayed) I can detail my answer.

Remember to clean cache in each trial with `gatsby clean`.

Comment: i got it to work and it was ChildImageSharp, you are a genius! and thank u!